# Point cloud sensor position estimation

Tags: kinect, point-clouds, 3d-rendering

Let's sat I have point cloud data that I don't know the sensor position(and it is not [0,0,0]). Is there a good way to estimate original sensor position from it?

For instance, from the point cloud below,

Point cloud data:

[image: Point cloud data]

find viewpoint that allow point cloud looks like this.(like depthmap) So there is no (or least) holes can be observed.

Point cloud looks like this picture from viewpoint that I want to find:

[image: Point cloud looks like this picture from viewpoint that I want to find.]

Comment: If you're looking for an automated process, then I don't think that is possible (or at least easily doable). However, if you have two point clouds (instead of the 2D depth image), you can try aligning them using Point based gluing (in meshlab). If properly aligned, the rotation matrix would give you the origin of the sensor position, wrt the depth map point cloud.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wanted to find out if there is automated way..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically a point cloud reconstruction is done by capturing the object in different angles and aligning them to together. In point cloud this process is called **Registration**. So that there is no static position to the kinect sensor since in each frame, the sensor position in global coordinates space is not static.

So that I assume you are not asking about a point cloud which is gone through a reconstruction process, thus a point cloud which generated from a static sensor position. If that point cloud is not gone through any transformations (rotation, transition) and generated using raw depth data, then the point cloud is always generated in depth camera coordinates space where origin is the position of the Kinect sensor.

In your question it says sensor position is not [0,0,0], That means after capturing the depth image, it has been transformed to new coordinate space.(I assume the origin of the new coordinate space is the center of the given point cloud). So without knowing this transformation matrix, you can't get the original camera position(relative to the new coordinate).

Most impotently, when you say "position of the sensor", you need to specify the coordinate space which you are referring to. **position is always relative to the specific coordinate space**.

You can find the position of the camera as @Atif Anwer said **BUT under one condition**, either one of the two point clouds has NOT been  gone trough a transformation, thus it is in original coordinates space. Then you can find the transformation of the second point cloud relative to the first point cloud and apply that transformation matrix to [0,0,0] to find the camera position of the second point cloud relative to the initial depth camera coordinate space.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So as far as I understand your answer, there is no way to find position of the sensor(in global coordinate, after registration) automatically, under my assumption where there is no information about position of sensor for any point cloud segment (any single scan result).